# Coveo 5 - Sitecore 9.3 Install - Cannot activate and configure

Tags: coveo

Question on `Sitecore 9.3` instance w/ Coveo install:

- Downloaded the zip file for `sc9.3` -
  https://docs.coveo.com/en/lbic3150/coveo-for-sitecore-v5/march-18-2022-release-5-0-1110-1#downloads
- `Coveo for Sitecore 9.3 5.0.1110.1.zip` Made sure `Sitecore PS ext` was installed - `Sitecore PowerShell Extensions 6.1.1.38514`
- Installed the `Coveo pkg` (here in lies the problem):

On this page, https://docs.coveo.com/en/2344/coveo-for-sitecore-v5/install-coveo-for-sitecore-in-a-sitecore-on-premises-environment, it states on #10, that the "Coveo for Sitecore Configuration dialog will appear". It did not. I did not receive any errors w/ the installation.

After the "successful" installation ---------------------

- Within Sitecore, in the "Templates", I see the "Coveo Hive".
- Within Sitecore, in the "System/Modules", I see nothing relating to
  Coveo.
- On Sitecore "Desktop", there is no "Coveo" column/icon. Should there
  be one?

In inetpub, I see:

- `/App_Config/Modules/Coveo`
- `/App_Config/Include/Coveo`
- `/sitecore modules/Shell/Coveo`
- `/sitecore modules/Web/Coveo`

In `/admin/showconfig.aspx`, searching for "coveo", nothing comes up

I then found this doc site, https://docs.coveo.com/en/3150/coveo-for-sitecore-v5/configuration-and-activation-options, which states, "Using the Coveo for Sitecore User Interface - When installing Coveo for Sitecore as a Sitecore package using the Installation Wizard, Coveo for Sitecore will automatically prompt you to configure and activate. You can also reach the activation page using its URL (see Configure and Activate Using the User Interface).

On that page, it states, `You can also reach the Coveo for Sitecore Activation page at http://<INSTANCE_HOSTNAME>/coveo/command-center/index.html, where <INSTANCE_HOSTNAME> is replaced by your Sitecore instance name.`

I then plug that into the browser and it tacks on the `/#indexes`, and states `An error has occurred while loading the index list` (which I would presume I do not have yet).

On this page, there are numerous errors in "Console". (see attachment).

I have also tried to go to this URL  `http://<INSTANCE_HOSTNAME>/coveo/command-center/activation.html`

[image]

Comment: You also need to check logs, I think you will find something about the installation.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to edit my post, it's much appreciated ::thumbs-up:: I'll remember to check the logs ;)

Comment: You get 404 error on Coveo endpoints. It looks like Coveo controllers are not registered in routes for some reason. Can you check that Coveo processors are present in initialize pipeline: Coveo.Service.Api.ConfigService.Processors.InitializeConfigServiceApiRoutes, Coveo.Service.Api.ConfigService, Coveo.Service.Api.ConfigService.Processors.InitializeConfigServiceSwagger, Coveo.Service.Api.ConfigService, Coveo.Service.Api.Framework.Processors.InitializeCoveoApiErrorFilter, Coveo.Service.Api.Framework ?